# How to add REFERENCES section in \tableofcontents

Tags: biblatex, thesis

I am developing a thesis. My previous paper used to show up with REFERENCESin the table of contents. Now it is no longer showing up.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} %use "twoside for two-sided numbering

%added by me
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{gsuthesisETD,multicol,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,geometry}
%%%MY additions
\usepackage{caption}
%for bibliography
%\usepackage[english,backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true
}


\geometry{letterpaper,left=1.3 true in, right=1.2 true in, top=1in, 
          headheight =12pt, headsep =20pt, footskip =1in}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%Toggles: "true" or "false" 
\figurespagetrue 
\symbolpagefalse  
\dedicationpagetrue
\acknowledgmentspagetrue
\copyrightpagetrue
\sectionnumberstrue

% Fill in These Fields 
\title{Design and Implementation of an Automatic Generator for Word Matching Interactives}
\author{Evan M. Gertis}
\degree{Master of Science}
\major{Computer Science}
\dept{Department of Computer Science}
\school{Georgia Southern University}
\thesistype{Thesis}
\graduatedate{May 2022}
\graduateyear{2022}
\keywords{Automatic programming, Computer science education, Online learning, programming synthesis, Word matching} 
\cochair=0  %choose 1 if you have a co-chair
\symbolfile{symbols} % symbols go in the file "symbols.tex"
%\captiontype=1 %not used at this time
\appendname{APPENDICES}  % or APPENDIX for just one
\tocheader{Appendices}
\mybibname{REFERENCES}
\def\deansname{Dean's name} % Do NOT use "Dr." here.
\committeechair{Daniel Liang} % No. Dr.
\committeecochair{Co-advisor} % No Dr. 
\memberC{Andrew Allen}
\memberB{Ryan Florin}  
\degreeA{B.S., University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, 2017}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MACROS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{rmk}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{dfn}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ass}[theorem]{Assumption}
\newcommand{\RR}{{\mathbb R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{{\mathbb C}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}
\newcommand{\NN}{{\mathbb N}}
\newcommand{\rank}{{\rm rank}}

\usepackage{dirtytalk}
% \usepackage[options ]{algorithm2e}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \makeatletter
% \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%                       \if@mainmatter
%                          \refstepcounter{chapter}%
%                          \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
%                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
%                       \else
%                          \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
%                       \fi
%                     \chaptermark{#1}%
% %                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
% %                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% NEW
%                     \if@twocolumn
%                       \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
%                     \else
%                       \@makechapterhead{#2}%
%                       \@afterheading
%                     \fi}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

%  Version: \today  % Comment this out for final version

  \input{abstract}
  \titlep            
  \copyrightpage  %optional (comment out if not used)
  \approvalpage      
  \input{dedication}  %optional
  \input{acknowledgments} %optional
  \tableofcontents 
  \include{Chapter-1}
  \include{Chapter-2}
   \include{Chapter-3}
  \include{Chapter-4}
  \include{Chapter-5}
  \include{Chapter-6}
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
  \include{8-Bib}
  

  \include{appendix}
  
%\scriptsize

%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
%\bibliography{refs}

% \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{myheadings}}
% \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Expected:
[image]

Actual:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={REFERENCES}]
```

To the 8-Bib.tex file.